# Unknown UPS back-up issues

Tags: power-supply, power, ups

I have a Powercom UPS IND606A. I am staying in India having voltage range of 230.

#### The detail explanation of problem :

* When there is a powercut UPS gives back-up but it restarts the computer. Sometimes, it gives back-up without restarting the computer.
 
* Actually, I  can change this product but the problem is that I faced the same problem with APC 600VA and V-Guard UPS also and this is the third time I am changing the UPS. 
So, I am not able to known where the problem lies :

```
1: Is there any problem with my house electricity but the electric engineer told,
   there is no problem with my house electricity.
2: Is this any problem with my PC powersupply which is a very old one 
   i.e.Zen-230VA SMPS but sometimes UPS does give a back-up without restarting 
   my PC.
```

The site for this Powercom UPS is : http://apexenterprises.in/index.php?route=product/product&manufacturer_id=13&product_id=112

Answer (score 0):

It's not you local power, the UPS should take care of "bad"electricity. The PSU however sounds fishy to me.